# WordPress custom order filter by last name in post title

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a custom post type for staff, that uses the post title as the persons name. In order to sort this by last name I'm using an order filter to find the last word in the title and then sort by it:

```
function posts_orderby_lastname ($orderby_statement) 
{
  $orderby_statement = "RIGHT(post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE(post_title)) - 1) ASC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

This works great for most of the staff which have normal first and last names, but I can't figure out how would I do this for names like (all should be ordered by "Clause":

Santa Clause

Santa Clause III

Santa Clause Jr.

Santa Clause Kringle

M. Santa Clause Sr.

I assume I can have a stored array and then check for those terms (like "Jr.", "II", etc.) or check for the length of the term found is greater than maybe 3, but I have no idea how to implement that into the code. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, this is how I solved it. You could expand on the if statement for all the edge cases you describe.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => 'page',
    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_parent'      => $post->ID,
    'order'            => 'ASC'
);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

// Order by second word in title, deal with edge cases
$lastname = array();
foreach( $posts as $key => $post ) {
    $word = explode( ' ', $post->post_title );
    $name = null;

    if( strlen($word[1]) == 1 ) {
        // Second word only 1 letter, so use third word if set
        $name = $word[2];

    } elseif( $word[3] == 'Sr.' ) {
        // Third word is 'Sr.', so use 2nd word
        $name = $word[1];               

    } else {
        $name = $word[1];
    }

    $lastname[$key] = $name;
}
array_multisort( $lastname, SORT_ASC, $posts ); 

// Loop through posts
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
   echo $post->post_title;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modified to fit my needs, because my names were like

Dawn A. Adelson

Timothy smith

John A. Smith, Jr.

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type'        => 'YOUR_POST_TYPE',
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'order'            => 'ASC'
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        // Order by second word in title, deal with edge cases
        $lastname = array();
        foreach( $posts as $key => $post ) {
            $word = explode( ' ', $post->post_title );
            $name = null;

            if( strlen($word[1]) == 2 ) {
                // Second word 1 letter and dot, so use third word if set
                $name = $word[2];

            } elseif( $word[3] == 'Jr.' ) {
                // Third word is 'Jr.', so use 2nd word
                $name = $word[2];               

            } else {
                $name = $word[1];
            }

            $lastname[$key] = $name;
        }
        array_multisort( $lastname, SORT_ASC, $posts ); 

        // Loop through posts
        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            ?>
            <div>
                <?php  echo $post->post_title; ?>
            </div>
          <?php
        }

        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way better approach, at least the other ones didn't work at all for me.
This will drop anything before the first space and apply a standard sort on the rest of the string. Make sure to modify `is_main_query()` and `is_category()` to your actual needs.

```
function posts_orderby_lastname( $orderby_statement )
{
    if( is_main_query() && is_category() ) {
        return "SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_title, ' ', -1)";
    } else {
        return $orderby_statement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try these plugins. It will help you.

1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/
2. http://wordpress.org/plugins/intuitive-custom-post-order/
3. http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-sort/

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry - I'm trying to do this without a plugin or dragging and dropping. My client should just be able to add staff, with whatever name and the front end should order them properly by last name. The function I have now *almost does it accurately with the exception of the weird name instances like I listed above.